# How to deploy Shopify app on vercel with prisma database?

Tags: shopify, vercel, remix

I have built the app using [shopify app remix](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix). I have deployed my app on the [vercel](https://vercel.com), after deployment in the vercel log I got errors. I have committed my DB on Git Hub directly as well but still got this error. Does any one know how to Shopify app deploy on the vercel?

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Prisma session table does not exist. This could happen for a few reasons, see https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/tree/main/packages/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma#troubleshooting for more information","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Prisma session table does not exist. This could happen for a few reasons, see https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/tree/main/packages/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma#troubleshooting for more information","stack":["Error: Prisma session table does not exist. This could happen for a few reasons, see https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/tree/main/packages/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma#troubleshooting for more information","    at /var/task/node_modules/@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma/build/cjs/prisma.js:21:13"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Prisma session table does not exist. This could happen for a few reasons, see https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/tree/main/packages/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma#troubleshooting for more information","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1250:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:526:35)","    at process.emit (/var/task/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:516:21)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
```

I have found the following solution but it's not working for me.

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix#database-tables-dont-exist
https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/serverless/deploy-to-vercel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vercel does not support [SQLite](https://vercel.com/guides/is-sqlite-supported-in-vercel). I was able to successfully deploy a Shopify Remix App on Vercel using [Postgres](https://vercel.com/storage/postgres).

I updated `schema.prisma`

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}
```

I also needed to modify the `create_session_table` migration to update the type `DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
"postinstall" :  "prisma generate"
```

in `package.json` should be enough.

You should also add a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable in Vercel, only for preview mode (with a different database) otherwise everytime you push to another branch with a different schema it will create problems when you try to merge.